# Zend framework 2 format url with parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework2

what do I need to write in the module.config file to accept a route in the folowing format?

```
/action/parameter/value
```

I think in ZF1 this was done by default
Thank you
Here Is my route, I tried but I just can't get it to work
what route I need is classes/less/value
where less is a query parameter

```
'classes' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/:lang/classes',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Classes\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Classes',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                    'lang'          => 'en',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'process' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:action]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'lang'       => '[a-z]{2}',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic module/controller/action route in Zend Framework 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938809/how-to-create-a-generic-module-controller-action-route-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 0):

To help you more, we will need to see your current routing.

You will basically need a simple segment route with your action, followed by an open wildcard non required section:

```
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/products[/:action]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Products',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wildcard' => array(
            'type' => 'Wildcard'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I added my route, can you please help further, I can't get it to work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Because your current route is nothing related to /action/parameter/value... It's /lang/classes/action You also have a 'less' constraint that I do not understand... Basically, your code can stay the same, just adding the may_terminate and wildcard subroute from the code I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like your route to contain a parameter. The way i updated your code below you are able to add one more constraint in your route. So it is action/less/lang. Consider the updated code below assuming i understood what you are trying to do.

```
'classes' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/:lang/classes',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Classes\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Classes',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                        'lang'          => 'en',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'process' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:action]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'less'       => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',//edit here
                                'lang'       => '[a-z]{2}',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```